# Allow mocks (double("object")) to respond to :call or :send like the supplied method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In a little refactoring mode, and I have a bunch of tests that have doubles that are stubbing out method calls, e.g.:

```
connection = double("api_connection", create_thing: double("thing"))
```

In this example, calling connection.create_thing returns me the `thing` double, as expected.

However, I've now changed the code so that the actual code is running like:

```
connection.send(:create_thing)
```

Which is causing a slew of errors:

```
Double "api_connection" received unexpected message :call with (:create_thing)
```

Since this is a refactor, I am reticent to just fix the test doubles to respond to call. Is there a way to set these doubles to accept `:call` like they'd accept whatever method is being passed to `:call`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this turned out to be a *PEBCAK* error.

`:call` is not a ruby object method -- what I was intending to use was `:send`. Replacing my code with `:sends`s where I had those `:call`s caused everything to work.

Good thing I didnt try to 'fix' the tests -- they were failing correctly.